# Creating a shortcut for a file using MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, shortcut

I would like to create a shortcut to an existing image file using MATLAB routines. My goal is to have a shortcut in a folder that i specify, to the image from another folder that i specify (for organizing purposes).

What i want to achieve is the same thing that happens when i right click on the image icon and select 'create shortcut' option, only changing the target directory for the created shortcut.

I have about twenty thousand images to orginize so copying the files instead is not an option(it takes a really long time).

I will really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can we assume you are using Windows?  On Linux systems this would be trivial using symbolic links

Comment: Do you want "Matlab-specific" shortcuts? That is, do you need the shortcuts only for matlab purposes? And if not, why do you want to do this with matlab?

Comment: Yes i am using Windows. And no, it's not for matlab purposes, i need to have folders containing the images that non-MATLAB-users can open and simply see the images (via Windows explorer). I use MATLAB to automatically decide which image will go to which folder (based on some features of the image)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to add the path (*addpath*) and then use directly Matlab behaves as if the images are in the same folder. [Check here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i need to create the shortcuts and use them outside of MATLAB (Windows Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

You could call a VBS script from MATLAB.
For VBS script see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156583.aspx

Then write a wrapper function in MATLAB calling the VBS script with a system command:

```
cmd=sprintf('cscript //nologo "%s" %s "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s"',...
    vbsfile,name,targetpath,workingdir,iconlocation,hotkey,desc);
system(cmd);
```